# Skip duplicate values of a particular iteration while printing corresponding values - My End Goal is to write it on a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I am trying to use set() in my code to skip the duplicate values in my iteration; This type of question might have been answered on SO, but when I am trying to do it in my script, I am not getting the desired output.

I am extracting device names using device['name'] and ip addresses in the API is given as; This is the response body of API for one such device for IP Address:

```
"DTO": [
  {
    "id": "3485893021",
    "name": "Alternate Addresses",
    "IPAddress": [
      "10.228.143.125",
      "10.228.143.253",
      "10.229.184.125",
      "10.229.184.134",
      "192.21.247.125",
      "192.21.247.188",
      "192.21.247.226",
      "192.21.247.254",
      "192.21.247.61",
      "192.21.247.92",
      "192.168.53.38",
      "192.128.167.74"
     ]
```

I have multiple IPs for a single device like above, but when I try this, I get device names as None for all the iteration and only the first IPs from respective devices are printed. What I want is to print all the IPs and print only their corresponding device name once. I am extracting this data from API.

```
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
for device in data:
    fqdn = device['name']
    for ips in device["DTO"][0]["IPaddress"]:
        if fqdn not in seen:
            print(ips, seen_add(fqdn))
```

This is the output:

```
10.228.143.125 None
10.23.54.6.8 None
10.23.6.1 None
10.22.16.34 None
10.122.25.189 None
```

I am expecting this in the python console output:

```
10.228.143.125 10.228.143.253 10.229.184.125 10.229.184.134 192.21.247.125 192.21.247.188 192.21.247.226 192.21.247.254 192.21.247.61 192.21.247.92 192.168.53.38 192.128.167.74 devicename1
```

and so on for other such devices...

UPDATE: This one prints exactly how I want, but now when I try to print it on a CSV file, fqdn and ipaddresses start falling apart. Can anyone help me on how to write this one in a much easier way?

```
for device in data:
    fqdn = device['name']
    if fqdn not in entries:
        entries.add(fqdn)
        print("\nDevice: %s" % fqdn)
    for ips in device["DTO"][0]["IPaddress"]:
                try:
                    ipaddress.ip_address(ips)
                    print(ips)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Not Found")
```

Output on python console:

```
Device: Device1
Not Found

Device: Device2
Not Found

Device: Device3
10.228.143.125
10.228.143.253
10.229.184.125
10.229.184.134
192.21.247.125
192.21.247.188
192.21.247.226
```

I have tried this to print on a csv file:

```
with open("BNA API.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    fieldname = ['BNA Name', 'IP Addresses']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()

for device in data:
    fqdn = device['name']
    if fqdn not in entries:
        entries.add(fqdn)
        print("\nDevice: %s" % fqdn)
    for ips in device["dynamicFields"][0]["values"]:
        try:
            ipaddress.ip_address(ips)
            print(ips)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not Found")
        with open("BNA API.csv", 'a', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([fqdn, ips])
```

This is giving me output:

```
BNA Name,IP Addresses
device1,Not Found
device2,Not Found
device3,10.228.143.125
device3,10.228.143.253
device3,10.229.184.125
device3,10.229.184.134
device3,192.21.247.125
device3,192.21.247.188
device3,192.21.247.226
```

On my CSV, I am expecting output like this:

```
BNA Name,IP Addresses
device1,10.228.143.125 10.228.143.253 10.229.184.125 10.229.184.134 192.21.247.125 192.21.247.188 192.21.247.226 192.21.247.254 192.21.247.61 192.21.247.92 192.168.53.38 192.128.167.74
device2,their ip addresses and so on..
```

The IP Address should be in the 2nd column and separated by a single white space.
This is my structure of JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "device1",
    "vendorName": "Cisco"
    "DTO": [
      {
        "id": "426945997-254",
        "name": "Category",
        "IPaddress": [
          "10.228.143.125",
          "10.228.143.253",
          "10.229.184.125",
          "10.229.184.134",
          "192.21.247.125"
         ],
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

This is the structure for one such device, I hope this is correct, because I couldn't put all the parameters, only the ones that I need for this code to execute.
Thank you!

Comment: `seen.add(fqdn)` returns `None`. What do you want it to do? do `seen_add(fqdn)` but don't print the result. and print the ip address with `end=" "` smth like that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The output I am expecting is to print all the ip addresses that are associated with the device, but print the device name only once.

Comment: can you provide what you've tried to writing a csv , even if it doesn't work so we can start somewhere :D

Comment: @MooingRawr Thanks! I have updated it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this data set to test the code:

```
data = [
  {
    "name": "device1",
    "vendorName": "Cisco",
    "DTO": [
      {
        "id": "426945997-254",
        "name": "Category",
        "IPaddress": [
          "10.228.143.125",
          "10.228.143.253",
          "10.229.184.125",
          "10.229.184.134",
          "192.21.247.125"
         ],
       }
     ]
   },
   {
    "name": "device2",
    "vendorName": "Cisco",
    "DTO": [
      {
        "id": "426945997-254",
        "name": "Category",
        "IPaddress": [

         ],
       }
     ]
   },
   {
    "name": "device3",
    "vendorName": "Cisco",
    "DTO": [
      {
        "id": "426945997-254",
        "name": "Category",

       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I wasn't sure on what you were exactly doing since your code was mismatching the key names, But this should work out for you

```
import csv 
with open("BNA API.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    fieldname = ['BNA Name', 'IP Addresses']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()

with open("BNA API.csv", 'a', newline='') as f:
    for device in data:
        fqdn = device['name']   
        try:
            ips = ' '.join(set(device["DTO"][0]["IPaddress"])) or "not found"
        except KeyError:
            ips = "not found"

        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([fqdn, ips])
```

`ips = ' '.join(set(device["DTO"][0]["IPaddress"])) or "not found"` is checking if IPaddress is an empty list be using Python's True-y detection meaning if the set returns empty it will take the `"not found"` instead

Edit: 
Seems like there's more to this question, if you have bad IPaddress or what not you can use a filter in the `' '.join()` like so:

```
bad_list = ['Firewall','Load something']
#...
#same code

try:
    ips = ' '.join(x for x in set(device["DTO"][0]["IPaddress"]) if x not in bad_list) or "not found"
```

The `if x not in bad_list` checks before adding it to the `.join()`, you can think of it as a filter while iterating through the list. If you don't want to type out everything to exclude you could change it to `if ipaddress(x)` and write a function called `ipaddress(x)` which returns True if it's a valid ipaddress and false if it's not.

Comment: This did the trick, works perfectly as I wanted to. `ips = ' '.join(set(device["DTO"][0]["IPaddress"])) or "not found"` this logic was hard to get. Although, for some devices the parameter has unwanted data other than ip address at that particular field. That is why I am using `ipaddress.ip_address` to detect or else just skip them. But, I guess i'll figure that out now. 
Thank you so much!! my hard work paid off with your help, been trying this since couple of days. I am still in the learning stages of API so it gets hard sometimes :(

Comment: The except handles if there's an `IPaddress` and `DTO` key, if there isn't then it just gives "not found" if there is then the logic explained will check if it's an empty list, if it is it will give "not found", if there are values then it will do what you want. API is nothing more than a response, and generally JSON is pretty much just a simple parse.

Comment: For some parameters, IPaddress has 'Firewall' or 'Load Balancer' which isn't relevant and I am just looking to not print those them, but print the device name. I tried with your code, but it prints Firewall or Load Balancer there.

Comment: Remember in chat how we said post everything you need, the test code you provided didn't have those nor does your original question states it. Anyways check edited answer.

Comment: Few details that I stupidly miss out on are so crucial to the code and it adds or changes the script. I thought, I have mentioned it in my long question, but skipped out. Apologies

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting this question as:

"I have a data structure containing several DTOs. Each DTO has a unique name, and a list of ip addresses. For each DTO, I want to print all of its ip addresses on one line, followed by the DTO's name".

If this is an accurate interpretation, then you don't need set membership testing or anything. Simply iterate through the values and print them.

```
data = {
    "DTO": [
        {
            "id": "3485893021",
            "name": "Alternate Addresses",
            "IPAddress": [
                "10.228.143.125", "10.228.143.253", "10.229.184.125", "10.229.184.134", "192.21.247.125", "192.21.247.188", "192.21.247.226", "192.21.247.254", "192.21.247.61", "192.21.247.92", "192.168.53.38", "192.128.167.74"
             ]
        }
    ]
}

for dto in data["DTO"]:
    all_addresses = " ".join(dto["IPAddress"])
    print(all_addresses, dto["name"])
```

Result:

```
10.228.143.125 10.228.143.253 10.229.184.125 10.229.184.134 192.21.247.125 192.21.247.188 192.21.247.226 192.21.247.254 192.21.247.61 192.21.247.92 192.168.53.38 192.128.167.74 Alternate Addresses
```

You might be thinking "actually I can't be sure that all of the elements of the DTO list have unique names. If a name shows up twice, I still only want to print it once". In that case, composing your own dictionary of addresses might be appropriate.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {
    "DTO": [
        {
            "id": "3485893021",
            "name": "FOO",
            "IPAddress": [
                "address_1", "address_2"
             ]
        },

        {
            "id": "3485893021",
            "name": "BAR",
            "IPAddress": [
                "address_3", "address_4"
             ]
        },

        {
            "id": "3485893021",
            "name": "FOO",
            "IPAddress": [
                "address_5", "address_1"
             ]
        },


    ]
}

addresses_by_name = defaultdict(set)
for dto in data["DTO"]:
    addresses_by_name[dto["name"]].update(dto["IPAddress"])

for name, addresses in addresses_by_name.items():
    all_addresses = " ".join(sorted(addresses))
    print(all_addresses, name)
```

Result:

```
address_1 address_2 address_5 FOO
address_3 address_4 BAR
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Kevin! Probably, it's be a mistake on my part, that I didn't mention the other JSON object from where I'm extracting the name from the API. I am running another for loop to extract the name as it isn't the one in DTO. I need to extract device name as `Device['name']` and ip address from `[DTO][0]['IPaddress']` like this. I doubt it will work if the for loop is only one for the 'DTO'

Comment: I'm not sure I'm visualizing the structure of your JSON properly. Can you post a complete representative sample?

Comment: Just added!! :D

Comment: Thanks for your help and time Kevin! @MooingRawr has shared his code that worked. :D

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) the seen_add *does* something, but it doesn't *return* anything, that's what is giving you the None's.

2) If you don't want them to be separated by new lines, you can't have the print in the for loop, you need just one print. You can build the string as you go: out_str = out_str + ' ' + ips

If you dont care about the order, a little flatten set should work:

print(' '.join{ips for device in data for ips in device["DTO"][0]["IPaddress"]})

Comment: This prints the IP Addresses of all the devices together in a single line., I got your 2nd point, but I don't know exactly how to think of a logic there in my script